# Input unsupported or doesn't exist in MakeFeatureLayer()

Tags: arcpy, sql, table, error-000732

I have the following code below to clean up a table to ensure that phone numbers and emails are entered in correctly, and am trying to debug my code. I am new at Arcpy, so I am still trying to figure out why I am getting a error for my `MakeFeatureLayer()` function... Although I think my query for phone numbers may be in correct as well.

Error:

```
ERROR 000732: Input Features: Dataset 
  \\\My Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\Contact_Table_CleanUp\Test.gdb\Con‌​tacts 
does not exist or is not supported Failed to execute (MakeFeatureLayer)
```

Script:

```
import arcpy, os

contacts = r'\\My Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\Contact_Table_CleanUp\Test.gdb\Contacts'
comTrkr = r'\\My Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\Contact_Table_CleanUp\Test.gdb\ComTrkr'
GISTrkr = r'\\My Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\Contact_Table_CleanUp\Test.gdb\GISTrkr'

gdb = "\\My Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\Contact_Table_CleanUp\Test.gdb"
  arcpy.MakeTableView_management(contacts,"Contacts_tbl")

  arcpy.MakeTableView_management(contacts,"Contacts_tbl")
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True

#arcpy.Selectbyattribute. All Null Updated to New

#Selectbyattribute QA/QC output table Contact_Status1
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Contacts_tbl", "NEW_SELECTION", "Contact_Status1 IS NULL" )
arcpy.CalculateField_management("Contacts_tbl", "Contact_Status1", '"NEW"' )
#arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_table, "CLEAR_SELECTION")  needed?

#Create output table to edit in Arcmap for Both Email fields
Contact_Email_Output = os.path.join(gdb,os.path.basename(gdb) + '_Contact_Email')
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("contacts", "NEW_SELECTION", "Contact_Email LIKE '%@%'" )
arcpy.CopyRows_management("Contacts_tbl", Contact_Email_Output)
#arcpy.AddField_management(Contact_Email_Output, "Editor", "TEXT")
#arcpy.EnableEditorTracking_management(Contact_Email_Output,'','','','ET_Date', "ADD_FIELDS")

arcpy.AddMessage("Contact_Email Table created, now on to Agency_Email")

Agency_Email_Output = os.path.join(gdb,os.path.basename(gdb) + '_Agency_Email')
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("contacts", "NEW_SELECTION", "FROM contacts WHERE Agency_Email IS LIKE %@% " )
arcpy.CopyRows_management("Contacts_tbl", Agency_Email_Output)
#arcpy.AddField_management(Contact_Email_Output, "Editor", "TEXT")
#arcpy.EnableEditorTracking_management(Agency_Email_Output,'','','','ET_Date', "ADD_FIELDS")

#String length for phone number.
Contact_Phone_Work_Output = os.path.join(gdb,os.path.basename(gdb) + '_Contact_Phone_Work_Email')
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("contacts", "Contact_Phone_Work", "NEW_SELECTION", "FROM contacts WHERE LEN([Contact_Phone_Work]) = 12")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("contacts", "Contact_Phone_Work", "NEW_SELECTION", "FROM contacts WHERE Contact_Phone_Work IS LIKE '%-%' ")
arcpy.CopyRows_management("Contacts_tbl", Contact_Phone_Work_Output)

Agency_Phone_Email_Output = os.path.join(gdb,os.path.basename(gdb) + '_Agency_Phone_Email')        
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("contacts", "Contact_Phone_Work", "NEW_SELECTION", "FROM contacts WHERE LEN(Agency_Phone_Work) = 12")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("contacts", "Contact_Phone_Work", "ADD_SELECTION", "FROM contacts WHERE Agency_Phone_Work IS LIKE '%-%' ")
arcpy.CopyRows_management("Contacts_tbl", Agency_Phone_Output)
```

Comment: If you are using Windows, you need to specify the correct path which includes the drive letter (e.g. `r'C:\temp\path\to\your.gdb\fc'`)

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with where you are currently stuck.  Perhaps look into using MakeTableView instead of MakeFeatureLayer.

Comment: If the "Contacts" layer that you are referencing is only an Attribute table, then the function will fail.  A FeatureLayer can only be created out of a FeatureClass of some form, whether GDB, shapefile, etc, not a Standalone Table.

Comment: Cross-posted as http://stackoverflow.com/q/42636761/820534. Please do not cross-post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on @GetSpatial's comment, if your `Contacts` is a **Table** and not a **Feature Class**, you will get the `000732` error *Con‌​tacts does not exist or is not supported Failed to execute (MakeFeatureLayer)*.

Try changing the `arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer()` for a [**`arcpy.MakeTableView()`**](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-table-view.htm)

```
gdb = r"\\My Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\Contact_Table_CleanUp\Test.gdb"
arcpy.MakeTableView_management(contacts,"Contacts_Lyr")
```

The rest of your script should work fine using a Table View rather than a Feature Layer.

Note I have left the name `"Contacts_Lyr"` here as you reference this multiple times further in your script.  You could rename this to make it not appear to be a Layer, but you will need to rename all instances where `Contacts_Lyr` is referenced.

---

In response to your comments, I have updated your entire script

```
import arcpy, os

contacts = r'\\My Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\Contact_Table_CleanUp\Test.gdb\Contacts'
comTrkr = r'\\My Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\Contact_Table_CleanUp\Test.gdb\ComTrkr'
GISTrkr = r'\\My Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\Contact_Table_CleanUp\Test.gdb\GISTrkr'
gdb = r"\\My Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\Contact_Table_CleanUp\Test.gdb"

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True

contactsTblVw = arcpy.MakeTableView_management(contacts,"Contacts_tbl")

#arcpy.Selectbyattribute. All Null Updated to New
#Selectbyattribute QA/QC output table Contact_Status1
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(contactsTblVw, "NEW_SELECTION", "Contact_Status1 IS NULL" )
arcpy.CalculateField_management(contactsTblVw, "Contact_Status1", '"NEW"' )

#Create output table to edit in Arcmap for Both Email fields
Contact_Email_Output = os.path.join(gdb, 'Export_Contact_Email') # To produce output named \\My Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\Contact_Table_CleanUp\Test.gdb\Export_Contact_Email
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(contactsTblVw, "NEW_SELECTION", "Contact_Email LIKE '%@%'" )
arcpy.CopyRows_management(contactsTblVw, Contact_Email_Output)
#arcpy.AddField_management(Contact_Email_Output, "Editor", "TEXT")
#arcpy.EnableEditorTracking_management(Contact_Email_Output,'','','','ET_Date', "ADD_FIELDS")

arcpy.AddMessage("Contact_Email Table created, now on to Agency_Email")

Agency_Email_Output = os.path.join(gdb, 'Export_Agency_Email')
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(contactsTblVw, "NEW_SELECTION", "FROM contacts WHERE Agency_Email LIKE %@% " )
arcpy.CopyRows_management(contactsTblVw, Agency_Email_Output)
#arcpy.AddField_management(Contact_Email_Output, "Editor", "TEXT")
#arcpy.EnableEditorTracking_management(Agency_Email_Output,'','','','ET_Date', "ADD_FIELDS")

#String length for phone number.
Contact_Phone_Work_Output = os.path.join(gdb, 'Export_Contact_Phone_Work_Email')
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(contactsTblVw, "NEW_SELECTION", "FROM contacts WHERE LEN([Contact_Phone_Work]) = 12")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(contactsTblVw, "ADD_TO_SELECTION", "FROM contacts WHERE Contact_Phone_Work LIKE '%-%' ")
arcpy.CopyRows_management(contactsTblVw, Contact_Phone_Work_Output)

Agency_Phone_Email_Output = os.path.join(gdb, 'Export_Agency_Phone_Email')        
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(contactsTblVw, "NEW_SELECTION", "FROM contacts WHERE LEN(Agency_Phone_Work) = 12")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(contactsTblVw, "ADD_TO_SELECTION", "FROM contacts WHERE Agency_Phone_Work LIKE '%-%' ")
arcpy.CopyRows_management(contactsTblVw, Agency_Phone_Output)
```

You may need to adjust how you select your phone numbers, as I'm not sure I follow what you're trying to do here, but I think I've corrected the inputs and outputs as required to get past the errors you mentioned.

Comment: ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Layer Name or Table View: Dataset Contacts_Lyr does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute).

Comment: @winscott68 That's because you gave your Table View a different name.  In your edit above you've used `"Contacts_tbl"`.  If you don't want to update the rest of your code, you'll still need to use `"Contacts_Lyr"`.  If you prefer to change the name to `"Contacts_tbl"` then you'll need to change every instance of `"Contacts_Lyr"` as well.

Comment: Now I get a invalid expression on Select by Attribute:                                                      File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 7221, in SelectLayerByAttribute
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression
Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute).

Comment: @winscott68 remove the square brackets `[` `]` from your expression - `"[Contact_Status1] IS NULL"` should be `"Contact_Status1 IS NULL"` as you are using a File geodatabase not a personal geodatabase.

Comment: ok I removed all brackets within my expression. Now it seems to not like the calculate field expression:                                                          "Contact_Status1", "NEW" )
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 3457, in CalculateField
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Expected identifier
Failed to execute (CalculateField).

Comment: @winscott68 This is because you need to pass your value `New` as `"New"`, so you need to surround that text with additional quote marks: `arcpy.CalculateField_management("Contacts_tbl", "Contact_Status1", '"NEW"' )` - note the single quotes `'` around the double quotes.

Comment: Now : "NEW_SELECTION", "Contact_Email LIKE '%@%'" )
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 7221, in SelectLayerByAttribute
    raise e
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Layer Name or Table View: Dataset contacts does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute).    Does this mean I do not need the table in parenthesis?

Comment: @winscott68 `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("contacts", ` should be `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("contacts_tbl", `

Comment: arcpy.CopyRows_management("Contacts_tbl", Contact_Email_Output)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 15279, in CopyRows
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 000210: Cannot create output \\ArcGIS\Projects\Contact_Table_CleanUp\Test.gdb\Test.gdb_Contact_Email
Failed to execute (CopyRows).

Comment: Am I not using parenthesis correctly? Or should I be using a different function to create a output table to edit?

Comment: @winscott68 I think you are constructing your output table names incorrectly, however it appears you have already used the same method earlier in the script.  You are trying to output to `\\My Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\Contact_Table_CleanUp\Test.gdb\Test.gdb_Contact_Email` which should fail because you have a dot `.` in your table name

Comment: @winscott68 What do you want the actual output to be called?

Comment: @winscott68 I have updated my answer to include full updated code. I think I've corrected the inputs and outputs as required to get past the errors you mentioned.

Comment: @winscott68 if you still have trouble after this I suggest you mark this question as answered and ask a new focused question as we are now way past your original question about `MakeFeatureLayer()` here

Comment: thank you for taking the time to help me understand the proper format for this code, I'm sorry I am not more knowledgeable.

Comment: @winscott68 No problem, you can only get more knowledgeable by trying.  My suggestion if you want to learn is to start smaller - work one line at a time to get it to do what you want and then move on.  If something doesn't work you just change that line or the one or two above, without needing to rewrite the entire script.  Once you have things working you add in additional data and a bit more complexity like looping. But always start small.